# I am using Session array to store id. I want to unset session for particular id by onclick function

Tags: javascript, php

I learning about java script and ajax. I created onclick function on button with id.

```js
function unsetfile(id)
{
 $.ajax({
  type:'post',
  url:'ajax/unset.php',
  data:{
   id:id
  },
  success:function(response)
  {
   if(response.trim() == '')
   {
    alert('Successfully Checked');
   }
  console.log(response);
  window.location.reload();
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="unsetfile('<?php echo $list[0]['id'] ?>')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
```

This is ajax unset code. So i want to know where is the main issue with the code.

```
<?php 
$value_to_delete = $_POST['id'];
if (($key = array_search($value_to_delete, $_SESSION['data'])) !== false)
    unset($_SESSION['array'][$key]);
?>
```

Comment: Could you please share a `print_r` or `var_dump` of your `$_SESSION['array']` variable?

Comment: so can u tell what i do

Comment: Just add `print_r($_SESSION['array']);` on top of `$value_to_delete ...` and execute the script. The content of this variable should be contained in the response.

Comment: We don't know how you have your data stored in `$_SESSION['data']` and `$_SESSION['array']` so need more info to even make a guess.  Either show us the contents of those two variables or the code that stores the data initially.

Comment: id is not found in  $_SESSION['data'] only is the reason, not unset the data. can you show how you stored $_SESSION['data'] ?.